# spacy installation error while installing build depeendencies

Tags: python-3.x, pip

Collecting spacy<2.2,>=2.1
  Using cached spacy-2.1.9.tar.gz (30.7 MB)
  Installing build dependencies ... error
  ERROR: Command errored out with exit status 1:
   command: 'c:\users\vignesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\python.exe' 'c:\users\vignesh\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\pip' install --ignore-installed --no-user --prefix 'C:\Users\Vignesh\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-build-env-9opljrjo\overlay' --no-warn-script-location --no-binary :none: --only-binary :none: -i https://pypi.org/simple -- setuptools 'wheel>0.32.0,<0.33.0' Cython 'cymem>=2.0.2,<2.1.0' 'preshed>=2.0.1,<2.1.0' 'murmurhash>=0.28.0,<1.1.0' 'thinc>=7.0.8,<7.1.0'

Comment: i was trying to install chatterbot and got this error while installing spacy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to run

```
pip install --upgrade setuptools
```

Then

```
pip install --upgrade chatterbot
```

If that doesn't work then check if you are using 32 bit Python. Spacy has dropped support for 32 bit and so you'll need to use 64 bit Python.

Comment: thanks i was using 32 bit it was working fine after upgrading to 64 bit